# Detect user click

Tags: python, selenium, click, user-input, wait

I am logging into a website using my own credentials, but 2FA is active. Therefore, I need a way to "pause" the script until I manually click the button with my mouse.

Note that the button is **always** clickable, so using an explicit wait like `element_to_be_clickable` obviously  will not work.

I know how to do this with `input()` via command prompt, but I would rather deal with the browser manually since the rest of the script also requires manual browser interaction.

I also know that I could wait until the script detects a certain number of inputted characters, but I do not like this approach because typos.

I know I could use an explicit wait in order to detect something on the following page, but I want to avoid this way in case I ever need to step away from the keyboard before submitting the data. However, I could set an unreasonably long wait period e.g. `WebDriver(driver, 999999999)`, but this approach seems super hacky.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: I know how to do this with input() via command prompt - we can even automate this part. so that you will not have to do  any manual interaction

Comment: @cruisepandey i dont want to manually interact with command prompt and the code will be random based on my cellphones authentication app or are you suggesting another way?

Comment: in python you can handle command prompt input I believe, we don't need Selenium for command prompt. Could you tell me briefly, what exactly your manual steps.

Comment: @cruisepandey steps are: (1) execute the script from command prompt; (2) script navigates to website and submits credentials; (3) website displays prompt requesting 2FA code -- at this point, i would like to manually check my phone to get the 2FA code and then manually enter it into the browser and manually click submit, but i cannot think of any practical way to pause execution of the script until i manually hit the "submit" button

Comment: @cruisepandey one way i just thought of was to literally attach a JS `addEventListener('click'...` with `execute_script`, but this seems really hackish too :/

Comment: Check with your ops team, they may give you an environment where you do not need 2FA at all. It should get by pass.

Comment: @cruisepandey im not crawling my own website... im running this script on the open web. do u have any ideas or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that may not work for everybody. Poll the URL...

```
poll_rate = 1
current_url = driver.current_url
while driver.current_url == current_url:
  time.sleep(poll_rate)
```

**Can anybody come up with a better solution?!**

I am shocked that it is almost impossible to detect user input in a practical manner.